# RemoveChild error for some id

Tags: javascript

few hours I try to know why sometimes my removechild don't work. After reading the forum I see some issue about the fact my removechild array reduce is number each time... But I don't know how to fix this issue... Do you have any idea?

EDIT: I justed updated the snippets
For replicate the issue I invite you to add 4 new div and delete the third one and the try to delete the others... One of them will cause some troubles

```js
function newText() {
  var text = prompt("Merci d'entrer une tache");
  if (text != "") {
    addElement(text);
  }
}

function deletediv(id) {
  var parent = document.getElementById('ft_list');
  parent.removeChild(parent.childNodes[id]);

}

function addElement(text) {
  var id = document.getElementById('ft_list').children.length
  var ref = document.getElementById(id);
  if (id == "")
    id = 1;
  else
    id++;
  var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
  newDiv.setAttribute('class', "line");
  newDiv.setAttribute('id', id);
  newDiv.setAttribute('onclick', 'deletediv(this.id);');
  var newContent = document.createTextNode(text);
  newDiv.appendChild(newContent);
  document.getElementById("ft_list").insertBefore(newDiv, ref);
}
```

```css
#ft_list {
  border: 1px dashed lightgrey;
  min-height: 30vh;
}
.line {
  background: lightgrey;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px
}
input {
  background: lightgrey;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="New" onclick="newText()">
<div id="ft_list">

</div>
```

Comment: Please share a working snippet demonstrating your issue. Is your `id` value valid?

Comment: Your code works fine as is.

Comment: Please tell us how to replicate the issue with the snippet in your question.

Comment: @gurvinder372 if you tried to add for examples 4 new div, delete the third one, then the other, sometimes i have an error message for one of them

Comment: You use a submit button, but you do not cancel the button action.

Comment: @epascarello I don't understand why we need to cancel the button action?

Comment: A submit button submits forms. Just use a type="button" if you are not submitting a form..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing the element as the `index` of parent's `childNodes` but if you *delete a record and then add again*, it won't skip the added records counter value.

Instead of passing the `id`, pass the element itself

```
newDiv.setAttribute('onclick', 'deletediv(this);');
```

and change the method as

```
function deletediv(el) {
  el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
}
```

**Demo**

```js
function newText() {
  var text = prompt("Merci d'entrer une tache");
  if (text != "") {
    addElement(text);
  }
}

function deletediv(el) {
  el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
}

function addElement(text) {
  var id = document.getElementById('ft_list').children.length
  var ref = document.getElementById(id);
  if (id == "")
    id = 1;
  else
    id++;
  var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
  newDiv.setAttribute('class', "line");
  newDiv.setAttribute('id', id);
  newDiv.setAttribute('onclick', 'deletediv(this);');
  var newContent = document.createTextNode(text);
  newDiv.appendChild(newContent);
  document.getElementById("ft_list").insertBefore(newDiv, ref);
}
```

```css
#ft_list {
  border: 1px dashed lightgrey;
  min-height: 30vh;
}
.line {
  background: lightgrey;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px
}
input {
  background: lightgrey;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="New" onclick="newText()">
<div id="ft_list">

</div>
```

Comment: I am curious to know, which one will be faster directly removing the element like you did or finding by id then remove ?

Comment: @Durga I guess find by id will be an extra step while `this` will directly give the object for removal.

Comment: Yeah I think this method is better thank you Durga and gurvinder

Answer (score 1):

update you function

```
       function deletediv(t) {
            t.parentElement.removeChild(t);
        }

        function addElement(text) {
            var id = document.getElementById('ft_list').children.length
            var ref = document.getElementById(id);
            if (id == "")
                id = 1;
            else
                id++;
            var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
            newDiv.setAttribute('class', "line");
            newDiv.setAttribute('id', id);
            newDiv.addEventListener('click', function() {
                deletediv(newDiv)
            });
            var newContent = document.createTextNode(text);
            newDiv.appendChild(newContent);
            document.getElementById("ft_list").insertBefore(newDiv, ref);
        }
```